# Counting the number of occurrences in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to count the number of commas and question marks in a given array. Here is what I have so far but it only returns how many commas I have. I am having trouble understanding how to also return how many question marks there are.

```
var str = 'hello, how are you today? I am not bad and you?'

function checker(str){
  var count = 0
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(str[i] == ",")
      count++
  }
  return `There is ${count} comma`
}
checker(str)

//this returns "There is 1 comma"
```

I know the code only shows to count commas. I am not sure how to also include code to count the question marks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite straightforward if we apply the same logic you  used for counting the commas.

You just need to add another variable for counting the question marks (`count2`) and include it in the message. Like this:

```js
var str = 'hello, how are you today? I am not bad and you?'

function checker(str) {
  var count = 0
  var count2 = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == ",") {
      count++
    } else if (str[i] == "?") {
      count2++
    }
  }
  return `There are ${count} comma(s) and ${count2} question mark(s)`
}
console.log(checker(str));
```

Comment: I had tried that before but it kept returning something like 48 commas and 48 question marks. Now i see that I had forgotten to add count2 when trying that solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: @6Ortiz Great! If this was useful to you, please [upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) this question for future readers and consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it if you think it fits the question requirements.